# Paying rent from zakat without telling the renter

Tags: zakat, helping

My friend is separated from her husband. She is living in my basement. This month she has refused to pay rent as she has not enough money.

Can I adjust her monthly rent from the amount of zakat which I have to pay?

As she pays me $500 for monthly rent and I have to pay $2500 zakat if I don't take rent for this month, can I consider that I have paid $500 zakat? I don't want to share with her that I have adjusted her rent from zakat money. Is it acceptable?

Comment: What will you do when you receive the rent the following month?

Comment: I can use it  to pay my debt .

Comment: You should at least tell the renter you pay as zakat so that she knows that she should accept  it only if she really feels in need. Ask your Imam to be sure.

Answer (score -1):

QURAN SURAH AT TAUBAH 60 IMAGE AND TRANSLITERATION
quran image At Taubah60

> إِنَّمَا الصَّدَقَاتُ لِلْفُقَرَاءِ وَالْمَسَاكِينِ وَالْعَامِلِينَ
>   عَلَيْهَا وَالْمُؤَلَّفَةِ قُلُوبُهُمْ وَفِي الرِّقَابِ
>   وَالْغَارِمِينَ وَفِي سَبِيلِ اللَّهِ وَابْنِ السَّبِيلِ ۖ فَرِيضَةً
>   مِنَ اللَّهِ ۗ وَاللَّهُ عَلِيمٌ حَكِيمٌ
>
> Innama alssadaqatu lilfuqarai waalmasakeeni waalAAamileena AAalayha
>   waalmuallafati quloobuhum wafee alrriqabi waalgharimeena wafee sabeeli
>   Allahi waibni alssabeeli fareedatan mina Allahi waAllahu AAaleemun
>   hakeemun

QURAN SURAH AT TAUBAH 60 IN ARABIC TEXT

QURAN SURAH AT TAUBAH 60 IN ENGLISH TRANSLATION

**SAHIH INTERNATIONAL**

(9:60) Zakah expenditures are only for the poor and for the needy and for those employed to collect [zakah] and for bringing hearts together [for Islam] and for freeing captives [or slaves] and for those in debt and for the cause of Allah and for the [stranded] traveler – an obligation [imposed] by Allah. And Allah is Knowing and Wise.

**MUHAMMAD TAQI-UD-DIN AL-HILALI AND MUHAMMAD MUHSIN KHAN,**

(9:60) As-Sadaqat (here it means Zakat) are only for the Fuqara’ (poor), and Al-Masakin (the poor) and those employed to collect (the funds); and for to attract the hearts of those who have been inclined (towards Islam); and to free the captives; and for those in debt; and for Allah’s Cause (i.e. for Mujahidun – those fighting in the holy wars), and for the wayfarer (a traveller who is cut off from everything); a duty imposed by Allah. And Allah is All-Knower, All-Wise.

**MOHAMMED MARMADUKE WILLIAM PICKTHALL**

(9:60) The alms are only for the poor and the needy, and those who collect them, and those whose hearts are to be reconciled, and to free the captives and the debtors, and for the cause of Allah, and (for) the wayfarer; a duty imposed by Allah. Allah is Knower, Wise.

**ABDULLAH YUSUF ALI**

(9:60) Alms are for the poor and the needy, and those employed to administer the (funds); for those whose hearts have been (recently) reconciled (to Truth); for those in bondage and in debt; in the cause of Allah; and for the wayfarer: (thus is it) ordained by Allah, and Allah is full of knowledge and wisdom.

**MOHAMMAD HABIB SHAKIR**

(9:60) Alms are only for the poor and the needy, and the officials (appointed) over them, and those whose hearts are made to incline (to truth) and the (ransoming of) captives and those in debts and in the way of Allah and the wayfarer; an ordinance from Allah; and Allah is knowing, Wise.

DR. GHALI
(9:60) Surely donations are only for the poor, and the indigent, and the ones collecting them, (Literally: working (doing) upon them) and the ones whose hearts are brought together, (i.e. newly converted enemies, so as to reconcile their hearts) and the ransoming of necks, (i.e. captives and slaves) and the ones penalized (for debt), and in the way of Allah, and the wayfarer; an ordinance from Allah, and Allah is Ever-Knowing, Ever-Wise..

**ALI UNAL**

(9:60) The Prescribed Purifying Alms (the Zakah) are meant only for the poor, and the destitute (albeit, out of self-respect, they do not give the impression that they are in need), and those in charge of collecting (and administering) them, and those whose hearts are to be won over (for support of Gods cause, including those whose hostility is to be prevented), and to free those in bondage (slavery and captivity), and to help those over-burdened with debt, and in Gods cause (to exalt Gods word, to provide for the warriors and students, and to help the pilgrims), and for the wayfarer (in need of help). This is an ordinance from God. God is All-Knowing, All-Wise.

**AMATUL RAHMAN OMAR**

(9:60) Compulsory charities (- Zakât) are meant for the destitute and the needy, and for its functionaries, and (for) those whose hearts require to be consoled (in all sincerity), and for the emancipation of the slaves, and for (the relief of) those in debt, and (for spending) in the cause of Allâh, and for the wayfarer. (This is) an obligation imposed by Allâh, for Allâh is All-Knowing, All-Wise.

**LITERAL**

(9:60) But the charities (are) to the poor/needy , and the poorest of poor/poor oppressed, and the doers/workers on it, and (those who) their hearts/minds (are) united/joined , and in the necks (freeing) slaves, and the obliged indebted , and in God`s sake/path , and the traveler/stranded traveler (it is) a religious duty/stipulation from God, and God (is) knowledgeable, wise/judicious.126

**AHMED ALI**

(9:60) Charities are meant for the indigent and needy, and those who collect and distribute them, and those whom you wish to win over, and for redeeming slaves (and captives) and those who are burdened with debt, and in the cause of God, and the wayfarers: So does God ordain. God is all-knowing and all-wise.

**A. J. ARBERRY**

(9:60) The freewill offerings are for the poor and needy, those who work to collect them, those whose hearts are brought together, the ransoming of slaves, debtors, in God’s way, and the traveller; so God ordains; God is All-knowing, All-wise.

**ABDUL MAJID DARYABADI**

(9:60) The compulsory alms are only for the poor and the needy and the agents employed therein and those whose hearts are to be conciliated and those in bondage and debtors and for expenditure in the way of Allah and for the wayfarer: an ordinance from Allah: and Allah is Knowing, Wise.

**MAULANA MOHAMMAD ALI**

(9:60) And if they were content with that which Allah and His Messenger gave them, and had said: Allah is sufficient for us

**MUHAMMAD SARWAR**

(9:60) Welfare funds (zakat) are only for the poor, the destitute, the tax collectors, those whose hearts are inclined (towards Islam), the slaves, those who cannot pay their debts, for the cause of God, and for those who have become needy on a journey. Paying zakat is an obligation that God has decreed. God is All-knowing and All-wise.

**HAMID ABDUL AZIZ**

(9:60) Alms are only for the poor and needy, and those who work for them, and those whose heart are to be reconciled (to be converted to Islam), and those in captivity, and those in debt, and those who are on Allah´s path, and for the wayfarer. This is an ordinance from Allah, for Allah is Knower, Wise.

**FARIDUL HAQUE**

(9:60) The obligatory charity * is only for the destitute and the really needy, and those who collect it, and for those in whose hearts the love of Islam needs to be instilled **, and to free slaves, and to debtors, and in Allah´s cause ***, and to the traveller

**TALAL ITANI**

(9:60) Charities are for the poor, and the destitute, and those who administer them, and for reconciling hearts, and for freeing slaves, and for those in debt, and in the path of God, and for the traveler in needan obligation from God. God is All-Knowing, Most Wise.

**AHMED RAZA KHAN**

(9:60) The obligatory charity* is only for the destitute and the really needy, and those who collect it, and for those in whose hearts the love of Islam needs to be instilled**, and to free slaves, and to debtors, and in Allah’s cause***, and to the traveller; this is decreed by Allah; and Allah is All Knowing, Wise. (* This applies only to Zakat. ** The new convert to Islam. *** To the fighter having no provisions for holy war.)

**WAHIDUDDIN KHAN**

(9:60) Alms are only for: the poor and the destitute, for those who collect zakat, for conciliating people’s hearts, for freeing slaves, for those in debt, for spending for God’s cause, and for travellers in need. It is a legal obligation enjoined by God. God is all-knowing and wise.

**SAFI-UR-RAHMAN AL-MUBARAKPURI**

(9:60) As-Sadaqat (i.e; Zakah) are only for the Fuqara’, and Al-Masakin and those employed to collect (the funds); and to attract the hearts of those who have been inclined (towards Islam); and to free the captives; and for those in debt; and for Allah’s cause, and for Ibn As-Sabil; a duty imposed by Allah. And Allah is All-Knower, All-Wise.

**ALI QULI QARAI**

(9:60) The charities are only for the poor and the needy, and those employed to collect them, and those whose hearts are to be reconciled, and for [the freedom of] the slaves and the debtors, and in the way of Allah, and for the traveller. [This is] an ordinance from Allah, and Allah is all-knowing, all-wise.

**HASAN AL-FATIH QARIBULLAH AND AHMAD DARWISH**

(9:60) The obligatory charity shall be only for the poor and the needy, and for those who work to collect it, and to influence hearts (to belief), for ransoming captives, and debtors in the Way of Allah and the destitute traveler. It is an obligation from Allah. Allah is Knowing, Wise.

Comment: I hope that this will make it clearly for you to define, otherwise ask a Imam. I only searched your question in arabic and seems that this will answer your question. Im not a person that can GUARANTEE a 100% right answer (  [FATWA](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fatwa)  )

Comment: This si not an answer as we expect her (see [answer]) and read https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/do-evidences-speak-for-themselves

Comment: Its better to give resources than answers because of the anonymity in internet. In order to issue an authorized fatwā using an individual skills of reasoning, it has to be a mufti or scholar who must meet the standards of ijtihād. Otherwise read those resources and compare it with your individual case or go to the nearest Mosque in your area and get an answer there. How else will the sister here be 100% sure that my answer or anyone elses answer is the right answer

Comment: I think it is fine to be prudent and refuse to make fatwa. An interpretation answering the question marked as a personal interpretation should be allowed and welcome, too. I think this answer is helpful +1